# How to script that multiple commands outputs are shown real-time?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to run a few commands simultaneously and observe their output in real-time. Ideally it would be an automatic bash script which runs commands `c1`, `c2`, `c3` at the same time and shows them in a grid view in a single terminal.

How can I achieve that the easiest way?

I've seen that `screen` could do something like that, but I'm not sure how to put that together. I'm using KDE Plasma, so I suppose I need to run that script with `konsole`. The commands are not always the same, so I need to parametrize them.

Comment: Hmm... is this a school task?

Comment: It's not a school task. I doubt schools would teach the command line. It's poor man's parallelization of analysis scripts.

Comment: In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1):

**Very simplest:**

**ESSENTIAL First, BASIC requirement:**
Make sure each command does a SINGLE quick update, prints the result and EXITS after that.

Create a text file with this content, save as e.g. **observer.sh**

```
rev="$(tput rev)"
off="$(tput sgr0)"

while true ; do 

  tput reset; 
  date; 

  echo -e "$rev--- c1 ---$off"; 
  # command c1 here

  echo -e "$rev--- c2 ---$off"; 
  # command c2 here

  echo -e "$rev--- c3 ---$off"; 
  # command c3 here

  sleep 1; 
done
```

Start it with `bash observer.sh`
*The script, as is above, shows a rolling date/time at top, 1 second update.*

To get the output in "a grid" is quite a bit harder; it involves manipulating the output window with e.g. ncurses commands via e.g. `tput` AND setting and retaining stdin, stdout and stderr for each command connected to each a separate ncurses-window - similar to what Bash does as it starts a command.

**Note:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/47502223/3720510 indicates that this isn't an easy task

**But then:** https://github.com/metal3d/bashsimplecurses
Simple examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEULy6oqrfM

Comment: Thanks! I tried it out, but my commands do not stop. Your version does not run them in parallel? The idea was that I observe their out as they keep running simultaneously.

Comment: To have them run in parallel IN THE SAME WINDOW is an advanced task, unless you find software that helps to achieve that. Easiest: Run each in separate shells (Terminals) to get them running parallel.

Comment: Added **ESSENTIAL** line in answer